# Android:Activity not rendering anything after Loading content from RSS Feed

Tags: android, rss

I am trying to read a RSS feed from a URL and show it as a ListView on my app.

Initially I was facing issues such as **Networking on Main Activity** due to which I transformed the method and called it via a new thread.

Now I am not getting any exception but I cannot see the results on the screen.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.learning.vikash.newsreaderapplication;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    List Headlines=new ArrayList();
    List links=new ArrayList();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try{
                    URL url=new URL("http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/bangalore/?service=rss");
                    XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

                    XmlPullParser xPP=factory.newPullParser();
                    xPP.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");

                    boolean insideItem=false;
                    int eventType=xPP.getEventType();

                    while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                        if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                            if(xPP.getName().equals("item")){
                                insideItem=true;
                            }else if(xPP.getName().equals("title")){
                                if(insideItem){
                                    Headlines.add(xPP.getText());
                                    Log.d("RSS Feed1",xPP.getText());
                                }
                            }else if(xPP.getName().equals("link")){
                                if(insideItem){
                                    links.add(xPP.getText());
                                    Log.d("RSS Feed2", xPP.getText());
                                }
                            }
                        }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xPP.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                            insideItem=false;
                        }
                        xPP.next();
                    }
                }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
        thread.start();
        //Changed to run on UI Thread
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.content_main,Headlines);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   /* @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/
}
```

And my android_manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.learning.vikash.newsreaderapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.learning.vikash.newsreaderapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am fairly new to Android, but since there is no error or result, I am unable to understand.
Kindly help.

Comment: you are updating list in a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have API call or Webservice call in **AsyncTask**, Android does not allows network request on main thread, as per our requirement it is also necessary that we need to have some UI related funtions on response of request. AsyncTask manages the best. You can also use third party libs like oktthp, volley, retrofit, etc.
Have a glance on some [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

Comment: was able to do it using asyncTask.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Make the headlines list a member variable of your class so you can get it outside your background thread and then move:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.content_main,Headlines);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

to another runnable and execute that using Activity's runOnUiThread() method.

I think your issue is occurring because you're doing UI updates in a background thread instead of the UI thread which can lead to unexpected issues.

EDIT::
Place the runOnUiThread call with the adapter runnable in the try block after your while loop. Right now you're calling the runOnUiThread method on your main thread, so it's going to update the UI once that line of code is run regardless of whether or not your data is fully loaded instead of when your data is to be displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try{
                URL url=new URL("http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/bangalore/?service=rss");
                XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

                XmlPullParser xPP=factory.newPullParser();
                xPP.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");

                boolean insideItem=false;
                int eventType=xPP.getEventType();

                while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                    if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                        if(xPP.getName().equals("item")){
                            insideItem=true;
                        }else if(xPP.getName().equals("title")){
                            if(insideItem){
                                Headlines.add(xPP.getText());
                                Log.d("RSS Feed1",xPP.getText());
                            }
                        }else if(xPP.getName().equals("link")){
                            if(insideItem){
                                links.add(xPP.getText());
                                Log.d("RSS Feed2", xPP.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xPP.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        insideItem=false;
                    }
                    xPP.next();
                }

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.content_main,Headlines);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
    });

            }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated my code , probably to what you suggested,but it is still not showing any details on screen.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify where to place your runOnUiThread call

Comment: I must be really foolish here, but its not working.I spent a lot of time yesterday figuring, couldn't find one.

Comment: I tried doing it using AsyncTask and was able to do it. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I still haven't figured why this did not work.